# Верстка игры под андроид

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Есть игра с несколькими скринами. Пользователю задается вопрос, он должен на него выбрать ответ. И есть таймер. Как лучше это засунуть в андроид, возможно как-то кастомизировать стандартные элементы. Или это все нужно отрисовывать в каком-то canvas'e ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу универсальной верстки можно решить ресурсами масштаба, привязанными к различным размерам экрана

Comment: Нет, я про то, как допустим сверстать подобный таймер https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/147713/screenshots/1005909/app-interface.jpg

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не писать самому, готовые решения уже существуют, нужно только немного поискать. Одну за вас я уже нашел https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar